Tikz: arrow with multiple styles
I am trying to draw an arrow as in the following picture:

In the past, I always solved this problem by simply splitting the line in three parts, adding two coordinates, and drawing three different lines. I am looking for a less ad-hoc solution. Ideally I would only to specify the length or the percentage of the solid/dotted part.
I thought I was getting closer using the decoration library. However, I can't find a way to make the middle part dotted (in the MWE it's zigzag). Morever, if I try to manually add a arrow head, that does not get placed where I expect it to be: I would expect it to be at the end of the solid part, but it gets placed well withing the zigzag part.
I am open to solutions that do not involve the decorations library if there's an easier way to do it.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=zigzag,
    custom/.style={decoration={ pre length=#1,post length=#1 }} 
    ]

    \draw[->, decorate, custom=1cm] (0,0) -- (8,1);

\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=zigzag,
    custom/.style={decoration={ pre length=#1,post length=#1 },%
    postaction={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}}, decorate}}  
]

    \draw[->, decorate, custom=1cm] (0,0) -- (8,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Here is a way to do it. Basic idea:

draw an invisible line, and place two nodes there to know these positions
draw all 3 parts

First, here it's done manually; note the node needs to get rid of all spaces to avoid drawing over the middle part; note the residual opacity:
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    nd/.style={minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt},    % no space for node left
 ]
    % ~~~ basic idea ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,2);
    
    \draw[opacity=.1] (A) -- node[nd,pos=.3] (C) {} node[nd,pos=.6] (D) {} (B);
    \draw[->]       (A) -- (C);
    \draw[dashed]   (C) -- (D);
    \draw[->]       (D) -- (B);

Second, let's define a \newcommand for it:
\newcommand\brokenArrow[7]{%1:A, 2:B, 3:pos1, 4:pos2, 5-7:style1-3
    \tikzset{nd/.style={minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt}}%
    \coordinate (A) at (#1);%
    \coordinate (B) at (#2);%
%   
    \draw[opacity=0] (A) -- node[nd,pos=#3] (C) {} node[nd,pos=#4] (D) {} (B);%
    \draw[#5]       (A) -- (C);%
    \draw[#6]       (C) -- (D);%
    \draw[#7]       (D) -- (B);%
}

The code below works with both cartesian and polar notation of start and end point. For simplicity, I left out tikzlibrary arrows.meta, which provides nicer tips.
Suggestion:

store brokenArrow in a .sty file
load it via \usepackage



\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand\brokenArrow[7]{%1:A, 2:B, 3:pos1, 4:pos2, 5-7:style1-3
    \tikzset{nd/.style={minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt}}%
    \coordinate (A) at (#1);%
    \coordinate (B) at (#2);%
%   
    \draw[opacity=0] (A) -- node[nd,pos=#3] (C) {} node[nd,pos=#4] (D) {} (B);%
    \draw[#5]       (A) -- (C);%
    \draw[#6]       (C) -- (D);%
    \draw[#7]       (D) -- (B);%
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    nd/.style={minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt},    % no space for node left
 ]
    % ~~~ basic idea ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (3,2);
    
    \draw[opacity=.1] (A) -- node[nd,pos=.3] (C) {} node[nd,pos=.6] (D) {} (B);
    \draw[->]       (A) -- (C);
    \draw[dashed]   (C) -- (D);
    \draw[->]       (D) -- (B);
    
    % ~~~ brokenArrows ~~~~~~~~
    \brokenArrow{0,-1}{2,-2.5}
                {.25}{.66}
        {->}
        {dotted,red,line width=2pt}
        {->,teal,line width=3pt}
        
    \brokenArrow{0,-.5}{10:4} {.5}{.8}  {->,purple}{orange} {->,teal,line width=3pt}
        
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

